# Generate a std::tuple of std::function from variadic templates

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, stdtuple

Suppose a function like

```
template <typename ...ts>
void f(std::tuple<ts...> & data);
```

I would like to generate a `std::tuple` of `std::function`, each with this signature: `std::function<void(t&)>`, where `t` is the corresponding type in `data`.

Something like:

```
template <typename ...ts>
void f(std::tuple<ts...> & data, std::tuple<std::function<void(ts)>, ...> functions);
```

I suppose using `std::index_sequence` on `ts...` somehow, but I could not figure it out.

Comment: Just do `std::tuple<std::function<void(ts&)>...>`. This unpacks the parameter pack after wrapping `std::function` and the signature type around it but _within_ the argument list of `std::tuple`.

Comment: Do you also have a predefined function template like `void foo(auto x)` from which you want to generate `std::function`s?

Comment: I just read your code sample properly. Your solution is almost correct, there is just the comma after the closing `>` of `std::function<>` that breaks it. What you wrote is a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) over the comma operator. What you meant to do is unpacking the parameter pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you can express the pack expansion like this:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
void f(std::tuple<Ts...> & data, std::tuple<std::function<void(Ts &)>...> functions);
```

though, I'd argue that requiring each element to be a `std::function` is pretty expensive. Maybe you want something more like this: ([c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20))

```cpp
template <typename... Ts, typename... Fs>
  requires (... and std::is_invocable_r_v<void, Fs, Ts &>)
void f(std::tuple<Ts...> & data, std::tuple<Fs...> functions);
```

or this: ([c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17))

```cpp
template <typename... Ts, typename... Fs>
std::enable_if_t<std::conjunction_v<std::is_invocable_r<void, Fs, Ts &>...>>
f(std::tuple<Ts...> & data, std::tuple<Fs...> functions);
```

It should be pretty straightforward to derive the solution in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) or below from the [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) approach, if needed. The advantage of these last two approaches is that the caller of `f` can provide a tuple of lambdas, functors, function pointers, or any combination that is compatible with the call signature of the respective `std::function` in the first approach.

Comment: Very clean solution using C++ 20! However, I am having trouble using with a tuple of lambda functions. I posted the code here (https://onlinegdb.com/f26GzthMe). Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @canellas your data had a `double` but your function took a `float`. That would cause a narrowing conversion, so your lambda was indeed not invocable with `double`. You could change all the lambdas to take `auto &` to avoid the need to repeat typenames for data and lambdas.

Comment: @Jarod42 also pointed it out at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76890899/traversing-a-stdtuple-error-when-using-auto-and-stdmake-tuple?noredirect=1#comment135554013_76890899. Thanks!