# Traversing a std::tuple error when using 'auto' and 'std::make_tuple'

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, stdtuple

In [Generate a std::tuple of std::function from variadic templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76886878/generate-a-stdtuple-of-stdfunction-from-variadic-templates/76886999#76886999) I learned an elegant solution for traversing a `std::tuple`, but I am facing an error I can not find out why. In the code below:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t t_idx, typename... t_function, typename... t_data>
requires(... and std::is_invocable_r_v<
         void, t_function,
         t_data &>) void traverse_each(std::tuple<t_function...> p_function,
                                       std::tuple<t_data...> &p_data) {
  std::get<t_idx>(p_function)(std::get<t_idx>(p_data));
}

template <std::size_t... t_idxs, typename... t_function, typename... t_data>
requires(... and std::is_invocable_r_v<
         void, t_function,
         t_data &>) void traverse_all(std::index_sequence<t_idxs...>,
                                      std::tuple<t_function...> p_function,
                                      std::tuple<t_data...> &p_data) {
  (traverse_each<t_idxs>(p_function, p_data), ...);
}

template <typename... t_function, typename... t_data>
requires(... and std::is_invocable_r_v<
         void, t_function,
         t_data &>) void traverse(std::tuple<t_function...> p_function,
                                  std::tuple<t_data...> &p_data) {
  traverse_all(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(t_data)>{}, p_function,
               p_data);
}

int main() {
  auto _functions{std::make_tuple(
      [](char &p_char) { std::cout << "char: " << p_char << std::endl; },
      [](int &p_int) { std::cout << "int: " << p_int << std::endl; },
      [](float &p_float) { std::cout << "float: " << p_float << std::endl; },
      [](std::string &p_str) {
        std::cout << "string: " << p_str << std::endl;
      })};

  std::tuple<char, int, float, std::string> _data_0{'k', -19, 8.014, "bye"};
  traverse(_functions, _data_0);

  auto _data_1 =
      std::make_tuple('k', static_cast<int>(-19), 8.014, std::string("bye"));
  traverse(_functions, _data_1);
}
```

When calling `traverse(_functions, _data_1)` I get

```
main.cpp:46:3: No matching function for call to 'traverse'
main.cpp:26:26: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with t_function = <(lambda at /var/tmp/baires/main.cpp:34:7), (lambda at /var/tmp/baires/main.cpp:35:7), (lambda at /var/tmp/baires/main.cpp:36:7), (lambda at /var/tmp/baires/main.cpp:37:7)>, t_data = <char, int, double, std::basic_string<char>>]
main.cpp:24:18: because 'std::is_invocable_r_v<void, (lambda at /var/tmp/baires/main.cpp:36:7), double &>' evaluated to false
```

I can not see the difference between `std::tuple<char, int, float, std::string> _data_0{'k', -19, 8.014, "bye"};` and `auto _data_1 = std::make_tuple('k', static_cast<int>(-19), 8.014, std::string("bye"));` regarding the constraint defined for `traverse`.

Comment: `8.014` is a double.

Comment: I am sorry, but I have to do it: kkkkkkkk! What a silly mistake in a (for me at least) complex code! Thanks for point it out, @Jarod42!

Comment: An elegant way to traverse a tuple is to use `std::apply()`: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/nxG8d5KaT).

Comment: @Evg: std::apply take only one tuple, OP wants to traverse two tuples...

Comment: Changing lambda to take float by value (or const reference) would also fix compilation

Comment: @Jarod42 the function parameter of `std::apply` needs an adapter that takes a tuple of unary functions and creates an n-ary one. Much simpler than original code.

Comment: @Red.Wave: The complexity of OP code is mostly just the `requires`. Especially, as it is also done for the helper functions (using lambda might reduce that). [Simplified code](https://godbolt.org/z/Wf6T9Gj8b).

Comment: @Jarod42 nop. OP: 3 templates + indexing + `std::integer_sequence`. `std::apply`: 2 templates, no explicit indexing -> more readable.

Comment: @Red.Wave: [apply](https://godbolt.org/z/Mh1YxdK38) vs [OP simplified code](https://godbolt.org/z/Wf6T9Gj8b).

Comment: @Jarod42 nice job with *one-liners*. `std::index_sequence_for` would save a few more characters in 2nd listing. Though I do such lambda voodoos a lot, they can reduce code readability. I am not sure which approach is better (one-liners vs separate impl).

Comment: Who is this 'OP' guy?

Comment: For me, separate implementation is far more readable. Using `apply`  makes the code harder to read, IMHO.

Comment: @canellas Not sure if sarcasm or genuine, but just in case: OP = original poster. Here, that would be you.

Comment: No sarcasm! I really did not know this! Thanks!